# Use Collections to order ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> comparing piece of string

Tags: java, string, arraylist

I need sort ArrayList of HashMap, this is my code:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> fiduList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

for (MapPoint aList: MapPointsList) {
    HashMap<String, String> fidu = new HashMap<String, String>();

    fidu.put(KEY_NAME, aList.getRealname());
    fidu.put(KEY_TYPE, aList.getType());

    fiduList.add(fidu);
}
```

getRealname get a string like this: AABB/CCCC/DDDD. For example:

```
AA11/4352/G435; 
AA23/0234/J543; 
AA02/0032/K123;
```

I need sort ArrayList comparing first DDDD, CCCC and then BB.

With my code I can sort only all string:

```
Collections.sort(fiduList, new Comparator<HashMap<String,String>>(){
    public int compare(HashMap<String,String> mapping1,HashMap<String,String> mapping2){
        return mapping1.get(KEY_NAME).compareTo(mapping2.get(KEY_NAME));
    }
});
```

How can I solve the problem? (I'm new Java user).
Thank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your sort from:

```
return mapping1.get(KEY_NAME).compareTo(mapping2.get(KEY_NAME));
```

To this:

```
String[] leftStrings = mapping1.get(KEY_NAME).split("/");
String[] rightStrings = mapping2.get(KEY_NAME).split("/");

int comp = 0;
for (int i = leftStrings.length - 1; i >=0; i--) {
  comp = leftStrings[i].compareTo(rightStrings[i]);
  if (comp != 0) {
    break;
  } 
}

return comp;
```

This breaks your string into the three parts, then sorts the strings alphabetically working backwards. The first time we see a mismatch, we report the sort order.

Comment: @Martin The approach in [Seelenvirtuose's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24201395/474189) is probably the better way to fix this. Unless you have a reason to use a map to impersonate a class.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest another approach. It seems that you use the map for holding two properties of an object - a name and a type. If so, a map is not the appropriate data structure.

You really should create an own class for it:

```
public final class Fidu {
    private final String name;
    private final String type;

    public Fidu(String name, String type) {
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

When continuing to analyze the requirements, it seems as if the name consists of three parts, which must be parsed from a delimited string. Thus, your class should reflect that (note the private constructor and the factory method):

```
public final class Fidu {
    private final String namePart1;
    private final String namePart2;
    private final String namePart3;
    private final String type;

    private Fidu(String namePart1, String namePart2, String namePart3, String type) {
        this.namePart1 = namePart1;
        this.namePart2 = namePart2;
        this.namePart3 = namePart3;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public static Fidu parse(String name, String type) {
        String[] parts = name.split("/");
        if (parts.length != 3)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(name);
        return new Fidu(parts[0], parts[1], parts[2], type);
    }
}
```

And finally, you should consider a *natural ordering* on the objects of type `Fidu`:

```
public final class Fidu implements Comparable<Fidu> {
    ...
    public int compareTo(Fidu other) {
        // an example:
        int compare = this.namePart3.compareTo(other.namePart3);
        if (compare != 0)
            return compare;
        compare = this.namePart2.compareTo(other.namePart2);
        if (compare != 0)
            return compare;
        return this.namePart1.compareTo(other.namePart1);
    }
}
```

Additionally this class obviously should also provide an implementation for `hashCode` and `equals`. Up to you ...

With that approach you do not need an `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>` anymore, but simply use a `List<Fidu>` (by the way, for the variable's types always use the interface and not an implementation). This list can then easily be sorted with

```
List<Fidu> fiduList = ...
Collections.sort(fiduList);
```

Comment: Maybe the name itself should be a separate class too. So we'd have `Fidu` with two fields: `FiduName` and the `String` type. (And maybe type could be an `enum`, but that's too much of assumption).

Comment: @isnot2bad Correct! And I always suggest against having enum types. That should be designed with sub types.

Answer (score 0):

In your `Comparator#compare` method you can use the class `java.util.regex.Pattern` to split up the real name using regular expressions:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\w{2})(\\w{2})/(\\w{4})/(\\w{4})");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(realName);
if (matcher.matches()) {
    String aa = matcher.group(1);
    String bb = matcher.group(2);
    String cccc = matcher.group(3);
    String dddd = matcher.group(4);

    // TODO: compare
} else {
    // TODO: real name does not match pattern
}
```

Notes:

1. You need to compile the pattern only once (first line); it can then be reused. E.g put it into a static or non-static member variable.
2. `\\w` matches the following characters: `'a'-'z', 'A'-'Z', '0'-'9', '_'`. If that's not sufficient, use other charachter classes or directly specify a custom character class like `[A-Z0-9]`

Answer (score -2):

Extend TreeMap create your own map class, In this class provide your way to sort the Map objects, for your string comparisons you can pass the Comparator with your custom logic to TreeMap class.

```
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html
```

This way all the functionality of the Map will be available to you and you can also implement your own logic of sorting.

Comment: -1 Complete overkill. Using a sort like the OP has is fine, it just needs extending.